# Installing opencv from source for python on centos

Tags: python, opencv, centos

I have CentOS6.5 installed. I have python 2.7.9 installed. I built it from source. The numpy 1.9.1 installed using pip.

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.10 from source. I ran following commands from opencv src directory using root previleges.

```
mkdir build

cd build

cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/python2.7/ \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 \
-DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy \
-DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ \
-DBUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON


make
```

I am getting following error.

```
[ 76%] Generating generated0.i
Generated 377 functions
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
/usr/src/opencv-2.4.10/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:15:33: error: numpy/ndarrayobject.h: No such file or directory
/usr/src/opencv-2.4.10/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void NumpyAllocator::allocate(int, const int*, int, int*&, uchar*&, uchar*&, size_t*)’:
/usr/src/opencv-2.4.10/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:184: error: ‘NPY_UBYTE’ was not declared in this scope


/usr/src/opencv-2.4.10/modules/python/src2/cv2.cv.hpp:423: warning: ‘cvmat_methods’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
make[2]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
```

Can you please help?

I build python with "--enable-shared" flag
I commented out line 50  string(MD5 hash "${lines}") /usr/src/opencv- 2.4.10/cmake/cl2cpp.cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
```

remove tailing `/numpy` and it should be fine.